# How to round image corner inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need image with rounded bottom corners inside rounded div.

I tried to set image border radius, but div exceeds image. Where do I make a mistake?

Is there a way how to fix it? Or do we have better solution?
Thank you for all answers

[image]

Here is my code

```css
.mainTile{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.mainTileHeader
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mainTileHeader h2
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainTileImg
{
    width: 100%;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainTile" style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="mainTileHeader">
            <h2>Header</h2>
        </div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/?random" alt="item" class="mainTileImg">
        <button class="button">xxxxx</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anything from stopping you using the outer div as a clip/mask container and just ignoring all rounding efforts of the image itself?  https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 5):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your image class. The default vertical alignment is baseline which is what causes the gap.

```css
.mainTile {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.mainTileHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mainTileHeader h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainTileImg {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainTile" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="mainTileHeader">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/?random" alt="item" class="mainTileImg">
  <button class="button">xxxxx</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That space there is caused because the img is an inline element and like all inline element they have to care about [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) which are those letter that goes under the base like like `g and p`.

one solution of many would be to set font-size 0 on the container that hold the `img` yes this will make the text disappear in the children, so you just set it back on the those children.

```css
.mainTile {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 0;
  /* Added */
}

.mainTileHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Added */
}

.mainTileHeader h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainTileImg {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainTile" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="mainTileHeader">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/?random" alt="item" class="mainTileImg">
  <button class="button">xxxxx</button>
</div>
```